# display count of numeric and non numeric column value in a single row in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table test with a column names which have both integer as well as non integer values

```
+------------+
| names      |
+------------+
| 123        |
| 123abc     |
| 89         |
| dkkjdk     |
| dkdn       |
+------------+
```

I would like to display the count of integer and non integer values in a single row like this

```
integer_count non_integer_count
2               3
```

I tried to print integer values using this query

```
select cast(names as signed) as int_val from test;
```

But I got this result

```
+---------+
| int_val |
+---------+
|     123 |
|     123 |
|      89 |
|       0 |
|       0 |
+---------+
```

The name field is a varchar(20) field.

Comment: How non integer count is 5 should't it be 3 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN not names REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' THEN 1 END) AS ALPHA, COUNT(CASE WHEN names REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' THEN 1 END) AS DIGIT FROM test;
```

Output

```
+-------+-------+
| ALPHA | DIGIT |
+-------+-------+
|     3 |     2 |
+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a sum of a condition based on regex:

```
select
    sum(names rlike '^[0-9]+$') integer_count,
    sum(names not rlike '^[0-9]+$') non_integer_count
from test
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c60d2/3)

Some explanation:

- `rlike` is the regex version of `like`
- the regex `^[0-9]+$` matches if the *entire* value is one or more digits. Note the `^` and `$`, without which it would test for digit(s) *anywhere* in the value
- using `sum(condition)` counts how many times the condition was true, because (in mysql) true is 1 and false is 0

Comment: This counts all rows without digits instead of all digits per row.  Might be what the OP is after :)

Comment: @bohemain What if one wish to display int and non-integer values in 2 different columns

Comment: @AnuragSharma it is in two columns. Visit the SQLFiddle link to see the query in action using your sample data and producing the counts as two columns in one row

Comment: @Bohemian Thanks for the answer, but now I would like to display the names.. not the count in 2 columns(integer and non integer)

Comment: Then you should ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 10 calls to `replace` to get the name without digits.  You can then calculate the number of digits by comparing the length of the name and the name without digits:

```
select  names
,       length(names) - length(non_digit) as digit_chars
,       length(non_digit) as non_digit_chars
from    (
        select  replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
                    names, '0', ''),
                    '1', ''),
                    '2', ''),
                    '3', ''),
                    '4', ''),
                    '5', ''),
                    '6', ''),
                    '7', ''),
                    '8', ''),
                    '9', '') as non_digit
        ,       names
        from    YourTable
        ) as SubQueryAlias
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/506fb1/5/0)